# Transfer Attribute to Dual Mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've imported data to create a mesh. This attribute is then used to color the vertices. However, it is a spiky mesh.
[image]

I wanna use Dual Mesh to smooth it out.
[image]

However, then the attribute (despite still being tied to vertices) doesn't work in shader editor. Now, in the spreadsheet the attribute is still there. But it of course isn't showing in the shader editor.
[image]

How can transfer this attribute to the Dual Mesh data to show up in Shaders?

EDIT:
For clarity. This Works.
[image]

This Doesn't
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the Smooth modifier ?

Comment: That works. There's acceptable methods of accomplishing this. But I'm more curious of just how it would work. Since it seems like it should "Just Work".

Comment: I think you have the wrong "Source position" plugged in. Since at the time the dual mesh has been converted, the attribute has already been destroyed. Try plugging the geometry output of the set position node

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of material lost. Add set material after Dual Mesh:

[image]

Just in case: after Geometry nodes, you should use **Attribute** node, then you want to get access to UV or vertex colors.

[image]

This is known issue https://developer.blender.org/T85962

Comment: This doesn't seem relevant. This is not UVData. It is an attribute loaded onto each vertex which is then used to color the surface. Like you have there with the Attribute. Except, when I add Dual Mesh in the Geometry nodes tree the attribute doesn't seem to be passed to shaders as expected.

Comment: @TheJeran Check out the update

Comment: There it is! You're the guvnah